# Timer implementation for rpc method

Tags: go, timer

I have a Go RPC server that serves client requests. A client requests work (or task) from the server and the server assigns a task to the client. The server expects workers (or clients) to finish any task within a time limit. Therefore a timeout event callback mechanism is required on the server-side.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
func (l *Listener) RequestHandler(request string, reply string) error {
    // some other work
    // ....
    _timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 5) // timer for 2 seconds
    go func() {
        // simulates a client not replying case, with timeout of 2 sec
        y := <-_timer.C
        fmt.Println("TimeOut for client")
        // revert state changes becasue of client fail
    }()

    // set reply
    // update some states
    return nil
}
```

In the above snippet for each request from a worker (or a client) the handler in the server-side starts a timer and a goroutine. The goroutine reverts the changes done by the handler function before sending a reply to the client.

Is there any way of creating a "set of timers" and blocking wait on the "set of timers" ? Further, whenever a timer expires the blocking wait wakes up and provides us with the timer handles. Depending on the timer type we can perform different expiry handler functions in the runtime.

I am trying to implement a similar mechanism in Go that we can implement in C++ with `timerfd with epoll`.

Full code for the sample implementation of timers in Go. [server.go](https://play.golang.org/p/OcGJ7QpfZuo) and [client.go](https://play.golang.org/p/m9T6R_OD3yk).

Comment: Why do you need a "set of timers"?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Let's suppose a single RPC methods need to talk to several other processes and each of these communication needs to have a timer,

Comment: Normally, every request on the server side runs in its own goroutine. You might be overthinking your problem. For timeouts, use context with timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to explored the *context* package

it can be be done like this:

```
func main() {
    c := context.Background()
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    f(c, wg)
    wg.Wait()
}

func f(c context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c, _ = context.WithTimeout(c, 3*time.Second)
    wg.Add(1)

    go func(c context.Context) {
        defer wg.Done()
        select {
        case <-c.Done():
            fmt.Println("f() Done:", c.Err())
            return
        case r := <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("f():", r)
        }
    }(c)
}
```

basically you initiate a base context and then derive other contexts from it, when a context is terminated, either by passing the time or a call to its *close*, it closes its *Done* channel and the *Done* channel of all the contexts that are derived from it.